# How do you display the Serial Monitor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, embedded

Trying to switch to VS code because I like it more.

Was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnEvJXpxxNM

I got a message saying it opened and no more information was printed, even though I have print statements in loop.

I set the output to COM3 for my UNO board. I tried every possible baud rate, nothing seems to work.

How could I start the serial monitor in VS Code?

Comment: FYI for on-lookers this question is about using the *Arduino extension* which must be installed. There are others which may or may not do what you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since are switching to vscode I recommend checking platform.io extension it make it so much easier to deal with microcontrollers using this tool

Comment: okay, but you don't answer the question how to open a serial monitor even if you have Platformio installed, or?

Comment: from Platformio tab go to your selected micro controller  make sure to manage the speed of the monitor  in the env variables

Answer (score 4):

To start the serial monitor in Visual Studio Code go to the command palate Ctrl + Shift + P and enter “serial” then select Focus on Serial Monitor View. The serial monitor enumerates the available ports in the Port dop down box. You can set the baud rate and line ending mode in their own drop down boxes.